# R: plotting data.frame against time with "hardcoded" date column

Tags: r

I have googled a lot and yet I still cant figure this one out. I am trying to plot one column in a dataframe against time, however my date column is "hardcoded" (for the lack of a better word) as index in the dataframe not a DATE column, as a variable, by itself.

```
> head(tmp)[1]
```

this is what I get, the 1st column is Returns:

```
                      RETURNS
2010-01-13 00:00:00  0.8291384
2010-01-14 00:00:00  0.2423567
2010-01-15 00:00:00 -1.0882186
2010-01-19 00:00:00  1.2422194
2010-01-20 00:00:00 -1.0654438
2010-01-21 00:00:00 -1.9126605
```

If I plot it like:

```
plot(tmp$RETURNS)
```

I get a plot of returns against index from 1 to 1500 (number of obs.) and not time. If I got a distinct time column I would plot it like this and it would be fine:

```
plot(tmp$DATE, tmp$RETURNS)
```

However, I dont know how to extract the date from that "hardcoded" date column, if that makes sense. I tried to convert it to other objects, timeSeries, zoo etc. Didnt help.I am sure there is some kind of simple function, I just cant find it. Thanks for any help guys.

EDIT:
Thanks guys, your help is very much appreciated. All answers are great, too bad that I cant accept them all ;) Of course it was **rownames** what I was looking for.

Comment: `tmp$datetimes <- as.POSIXct(rownames(tmp), tz = "GMT")`

Comment: it s not hardcoded, the stamps are row.names. I.e. tmp$time<-row.names(tmp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the input is as in the Note below then using zoo we can plot using classic graphics, ggplot2 and lattice as follows.  We also show a base R solution at the end and a variation.  Note that since the time is always 0 we used `"Date"` class for the time index in all cases.

```
library(zoo)
z <- zoo(df$RETURNS, as.Date(rownames(df)))

plot(z)

library(ggplot2)
autoplot(z)

library(lattice)
xyplot(z)

# this one does not use any packages
df2 <- data.frame(time = as.Date(rownames(df)), RETURNS = df$RETURNS)
plot(RETURNS ~ time, df2)

# this also works using df2 just calculated
plot(df2)
```

**Note:**  We assume the input is:

```
df <- data.frame(
  RETURNS = c(0.8291384, 0.2423567,-1.0882186, 1.2422194,-1.0654438,-1.9126605),
  row.names = c("2010-01-13 00:00:00", "2010-01-14 00:00:00", "2010-01-15 00:00:00", 
    "2010-01-19 00:00:00","2010-01-20 00:00:00","2010-01-21 00:00:00"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Reproducing your data (you should really have used `dput` to make life easier for us):

```
df <- as.data.frame(c(0.8291384, 0.2423567,-1.0882186, 1.2422194,-1.0654438,-1.9126605))
names(df) <- c("RETURNS")
rownames(df) <- c("2010-01-13 00:00:00", "2010-01-14 00:00:00", "2010-01-15 00:00:00", "2010-01-19 00:00:00","2010-01-20 00:00:00","2010-01-21 00:00:00")
df

                       RETURNS
2010-01-13 00:00:00  0.8291384
2010-01-14 00:00:00  0.2423567
2010-01-15 00:00:00 -1.0882186
2010-01-19 00:00:00  1.2422194
2010-01-20 00:00:00 -1.0654438
2010-01-21 00:00:00 -1.9126605
```

Cleaning up:

```
df$Date <- as.Date(rownames(df))
rownames(df) <- NULL
df

     RETURNS       Date
1  0.8291384 2010-01-13
2  0.2423567 2010-01-14
3 -1.0882186 2010-01-15
4  1.2422194 2010-01-19
5 -1.0654438 2010-01-20
6 -1.9126605 2010-01-21
```

Plotting:

```
plot(df$Date, df$RETURNS)
```

[image]

or

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x=Date, y=RETURNS)) + geom_point() + scale_x_date()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Les, great answer as well.